# Can't set :selected => for drop down box

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A user who has already taken a survey earlier on is presented with a form to fill out his/her address. The user has already supplied the state they live in at the time they filled out the survey.

As a courtesy I would like to preselect the drop-down with the state they selected. I am using an array us_states to pre-load the drop-down. The shorthand name of the state is saved to the db in the User model. The following select doesn't not preselect the state and the state that appears in the drop box is the first state in the array: 'Alabama'. The generated HTML is below.

```
<%= f.select :state, options_for_select(us_states), :selected => @user.state %>


<select id="pub_state" name="pub[state]"><option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
...
</select>



 def us_states
      [
        ['Alabama', 'AL'],
        ['Alaska', 'AK'],
        ['Arizona', 'AZ'],
      ...
      ]
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the selected option to the options_for_select method:

```
options_for_select(us_states, @user.state)
```

Comment: From what I can see in the source code, options_for_select is generating the HTML tags itself, including the selected attribute. I would say that if you remove the options_for_select and pass in the options directly then you will also be able to use the :selected attribute.